# How to inherit MudButton and MudMenu with my default values

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

There are many MudButtons and MudMenus in a Blazor page and I am trying to remove repeated properties like Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="Color.Primary" Size="Size.Medium".

So, I added custom MudButton razor component which inherits MudButton as the followings;

```
@inherits MudButton


@{
    //Is it required?
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        this.Variant = Variant.Outlined;
        this.Color = Color.Primary;
        this.Size = Size.Medium;
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }

}
```

```
@inherits MudMenu

@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.Variant = Variant.Outlined;
        this.Color = Color.Primary;
        this.Size = Size.Medium;
        
        this.EndIcon = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown;
        this.IconColor = Color.Primary;

        this.AnchorOrigin = Origin.BottomCenter;
    }

}
```

However, the custom MudButton and MudMenu could not be rendered correctly - only text was displayed.

Is it any way to inherit MudComponent with original style kept?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a normal class file `.cs` **not** `.razor`. This stops the razor compiler being invoked and clobbering the inherited RenderFragment.

```cs
public class AppButton : MudButton
{
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        this.Variant = Variant.Outlined;
        this.Color = Color.Primary;
        this.Size = Size.Medium;
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}


public class AppMenu : MudMenu
{
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        this.Variant = Variant.Outlined;
        this.Color = Color.Primary;
        this.Size = Size.Medium;

        this.EndIcon = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown;
        this.IconColor = Color.Primary;

        this.AnchorOrigin = Origin.BottomCenter;
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

Now you have two new components inheriting mudblazor with defaults set. `<AppButton />` and `<AppMenu />`

Comment: But what if I am want use components and write html code in my custom button class?

Answer (score 2):

My referred way is to override them in CTor (as long as they are not required!).  You can then set any specific preferences in the individual Razor declarations.

```cs
public class MyMudButton : MudButton
{
    public MyMudButton()
    {
        this.Variant = Variant.Outlined;
        this.Color = Color.Primary;
        this.Size = Size.Medium;
    }
}
```

If you want to use Razor you need to deal with the default RenderFragment.

```cs
@inherits MudButton

@this.ParentContent

@code {
    public RenderFragment ParentContent;

    public MyMudButton()
    {
        ParentContent = (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);

        this.Variant = Variant.Outlined;
        this.Color = Color.Primary;
        this.Size = Size.Medium;
    }
}
```